# Optimization algorithms for problems with variable objective function

Tags: optimization, heuristics, cpu

Let us assume a single objective binary optimization problem, where you need to solve it 20,000 times (approx) in order to tune some coefficients. The objective function includes two components. The first component captures the immediate cost while the second component captures the future estimated cost. The latter component is built based on a basic function that includes some coefficients. Each time the problem is solved, the coefficient can change, which means that the main objective function is changing. Here, I need an algorithm capable of finding good quality solutions while being efficient in terms of CPU time (because I need to solve the problem several times, e.g., 20,000 times or even more).

I was thinking that logic-based, population-based heuristics might be an option. However, I am not sure whether they can be capable of dealing with the variability of the objective function components. I was wondering whether you have any suggestions for such problems (pls assume that commercial solvers are not a good choice because of computational limitations).

==============================================

**Update:**

The problem includes one binary variable set ($z_{pbti}$), which may include 600,000 variables. The number of constraints can be also around 75,000. Below, you can find the constraint sets of the problem:
[image]

Comment: What are the order of magnitude of the number of variables and constraints?

Comment: I update the post to answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: The $z_{pbti}$ variables are all binary, and they are the only variables (all other symbols are parameters, indices or index sets)?

Comment: That's true. There is only one binary variable set.

Comment: Then all variable involved in the constraints with rhs $= 0$ can be removed?

Comment: That is true. I will try to simplify the problem with your suggestion.

Comment: @fontanf You read my mind. :-)

Comment: Solving $20000$ with $600000$ variables might not be trivial. Even if 90% of the variables are removed in preprocess, you might need more than a minute for each problem with a tailored algorithm to find an optimized solution, which might be far from optimal